# arm-linux libstdc++ difference in debug and release

Tags: c++, linux, arm, dynamic-linking, libstdc++

I'm going mad about this, so any help is really appreciated.

I have a C++ application compiled for arm-linux. I have two different versions:

- Debug (compiled with -o0 -g3)
- Release (compiled with -o3)

Inclusion paths, library paths and libraries are the same for both versions.

When I run the Debug version, it crashes (and I'm investigating why).

When I run the Release version, i obtain this error:

***../Appl_arm-linux_Release: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.20 not found (required by ../Appl_arm-linux_Release)***

I don't understand why the Debug version can work on a system where the Release version can't even load.

Comment: Are you cross compiling (i.e. host not equal to target platform)?  If so, did the target development tools come with their own libstdc++.so?  Otherwise, is the path to /usr/lib incorrect?

Comment: Yes, I'm cross compiling. I'm also running the application on a embedded system with a different file system respect to the one I used for compiling an linking. I can understand the library error, but I can't understand how can the application be loaded in debug.

Comment: I Think I have find out. When using -o0 libstdc++ is statically linked, so the application can be loaded even if the system libstdc++ is older respect to the one used by the application. Anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the -static-libstdc++ linker option to statically link libstdc++. From info [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html), it looks like you can still dynamically link other libs.